# Sort a string of text in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am trying to sort and use each link from the url list.
I have the below code. I have tried to debug but useless im to n00b.

```
$url="http://image.metglobal.com/hotelpictures/BG27FJ/0T300.jpghttp://image.metglobal.com/hotelpictures/BG27FJ/5D400.jpghttp://image.metglobal.com/hotelpictures/BG27FJ/6CW00.jpghttp://image.metglobal.com/hotelpictures/BG27FJ/IZQ00.jpg";
$urls=array();
$urls=split("http://",$url);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$urls[1]');</script>";
$arrayPoze= array();
for($i=0;$i<count($urls);$i++){
if($i>0)
$arrayPoze[$i]="http://"+$urls[$i];
}
$img0 =$arrayPoze[1];
```

Comment: Assist in making it less messy?

Comment: yes and to correct where im wrong

Comment: For starters, stuff inside `{ }` should be tabbed over.

Comment: Holy cow, that is indeed messy.. Care to explain again what you are trying to accomplish with this? Take your time :)

Comment: Spaces on assignments should be consistent.  How about instead of `$img0 =$arrayPoze[1];` and `$urls=array();` and `$arrayPoze= array();` a consistent space before and after the `=` like `$x = $y;`? That would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. Good luck & have fun.

```
<?php
$url = "http://image.metglobal.com/hotelpictures/BG27FJ/0T300.jpghttp://image.metglobal.com/hotelpictures/BG27FJ/5D400.jpghttp://image.metglobal.com/hotelpictures/BG27FJ/6CW00.jpghttp://image.metglobal.com/hotelpictures/BG27FJ/IZQ00.jpg";
$urls = split("http://", $url);
$arrayPoze = array();
foreach($urls as $val){
    if(!$val) continue;
    $arrayPoze[] = "http://$val";
}
print_r($arrayPoze);
```